# "Software installation failed" error when booting up

Tags: updates, installation, boot-loop, huawei

I got stuck at Huawei Logo and it won't start, then I followed this instruction

> Download the same build you had before getting stucked or newer one, Extract it and transfer "dload" folder to the root of FAT32 MicroSD, Put the SD in the phone, Hold Vol+ and Vol- with Power button to boot into Upgrading mode

Then when the installation shows up it automatically says "Software Installation Failed". How to fix this problem? I found that some say that it must upgrade a transfer package provided by R&D, and I don't know how to update it. I'm stuck in Huawei logo.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited for more than 5 years and no votes on existing answers). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

This procedure should work:

1. copy the `dload` folder(should contain `update.app` package provided by Huawei R&D) in MicroSD card (root folder) and insert the MicroSD card in your phone.
2. Turn off the phone by removing battery or pressing <kbd>power</kbd> button longer than 10 sec.
3. Boot the device in recovery mode by pressing <kbd>power</kbd> + <kbd>volume up</kbd> key.
4. once it is booted in recovery, select "upgrade using external storage" using <kbd>volume up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd> and <kbd>power</kbd> key
5. navigate to `update.app` package and press <kbd>power</kbd> button.

It will start the installation process and your phone should work after upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

It's a MicroSD card compatibility issue. Don't worry, your device is fine. The problem is with the MicroSD card you are using. Try an 8GB original card. Twinmos / Sandisk / etc.